# Replicating functionality of stackoverflow's tag system

Tags: javascript, jquery

On stackoverflow, while in the Tag-inputbox if you hold the left key button, it will go all the way to the left and open every tag for editing, same goes for the right key, and the backspace.

I am trying to replicate the same functionality on mine.

I have the following code: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hAKMN/)

The problem with the current code is that I am not sure how to implement the arrow keys movements.

Any ideas?

Comment: In fact, your code is not related to jQuery. This is pure JavaScript. How do you plan to have the solution: using the library or not?

Comment: This is not an actual question, you need to have a specific problem you need help with; "I don't know how to do this quite complex thing I want to do" is not something that can be given an authoritative answer. You should probably do some research, there are jQuery plugins that implement this functionality; you could either use one of them as it is, or study its code and learn how to do it yourself.

Comment: I tried doing it with pure javascript, but I did not really manage to. So I was looking for any jQuery solutions without any external plugins involved.

Comment: If you're expecting to receive _tutoring_, this is probably not the right place to seek it. Other than a full tutorial on tagging inputs, what type of answer do you expect? _Read_ the plugins code to see how they work; you don't need to actually _use_ the actual plugins.

Comment: I could not find a plugin with the arrow keys functionality. Otherwise I would look at the source code and do it myself. And because I could not find one, I came here to ask for help. I do not expect you to give me a step by step guide on how to build the system, but only a small code snippet that will get me going.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at these two jQuery plugins, maybe one of it will fit your needs (though they are not identical to the stackoverflow tagging functionality):

http://webspirited.com/tagit/#demos

http://aehlke.github.com/tag-it/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I already saw them, and they do not have the arrow keys functionality. I have searched all over stackoverflow and google for a plugin that has that functionality. after not finding one I came here to ask for help as a last resort..